# Babelloader multiple versions error when running npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm, babel-loader

Npm is installed on my machine using MacOS, and I'm getting an `ELIFECYCLE` error with following additional hints after I've run `npm run start` or `npm start`.

```
There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
[0] It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.
[0] 
[0] The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
[0] 
[0]   "babel-loader": "8.0.6"
[0] 
[0] Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
[0] However, a different version of babel-loader was detected higher up in the tree:
[0] 
[0]   /Users/user1/node_modules/babel-loader (version: 8.1.0) 
[0] 
[0] Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.
```

In case it was a Babel-Loader issue I removed it, and after that when I run:

```
npm ls babel-loader
```

It is coming up as still there, returning this:

```
react-scripts@3.4.0
  └── babel-loader@8.0.6
```

Babel-loader is not listed in the package.json file. I'm really not sure how to uninstall babel-loader completely, and if I did not sure if I would have to reinstall it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possible approaches depending on what the root cause is. The default answer is to delete your lock file and node_modules folder, and regenerate the lock file.

```sh
$ rm package-lock.json # or `rm yarn.lock`
$ rm -rf node_modules/
$ npm install # or `yarn install`
```

This doesn't always work. In case the issue persists, then do the following.

```sh
$ npm ls babel-loader # or `yarn list babel-loader`
warning Lockfile has incorrect entry for "babel-loader@^<bad-version>". Ignoring it.
warning Filtering by arguments is deprecated. Please use the pattern option instead.
├─ babel-loader@<bad-version>
└─ react-scripts@4.0.3
   └─ babel-loader@<good-version>
✨  Done in 1.17s.
```

Once you've done that, open your `package.json` and add the following:

```json
{
  // ...
  "resolutions": {
    "babel-loader": "<good-version>"
  }
}
```